# Remotely controlling multiple windows machines

Tags: windows, cluster

I'm looking for something like ClusterSSH, but for windows.

"ClusterSSH controls a number of xterm windows via a single graphical console window to allow commands to be interactively run on multiple servers over an ssh connection."

I want to be able to do the same on windows machines, but not necessarily over ssh.

Edit:
By "the same" I mean running commands, I don't want to control xterms on windows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for CLI access Powershell Remoting is what you want.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/05/10/remoting-with-powershell-quickstart.aspx

Allows you to run the same command on multiple machines.

If you have Certs (**not** self-signed) on your servers you can use SSL for the connections.